# What is the appropriate keyword for an Obj-C property whose setter method does not store the passed object?

Tags: objective-c

What would the most appropriate keyword be for a setter that never actually stores the object that you pass to it? (copy, retain or assign)

Specifically the endDate setter below never stores the passed date, internally it just updates the numberOfNights NSUInteger.

The corresponding getter re-combines the startDate and the numberOfNights to return a new endDate object.

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSDate *startDate;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger numberOfNights; //modifiable.
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDate *endDate; //internally stored as an unsigned integer, number of nights.
```

I feel the copy attribute makes the most sense.
(The pointer you pass in to -setEndDate: will never be returned by -endDate)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just to clarify, if I asked for `yourObject.endDate;`, I would get an autoreleased NSDate instanced that was calculated from the `numberOfNights` property?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you implement the getter/setter yourself then you don't need to worry about retain vs assign. These keywords only impact how the automatic getter/setters work. You can safely use copy here as well or just omit entirely. (I being this post with "I believe that..." because I'm feeling a little rusty and trying to get back into Xcode. Things have changed drastically this year with ARC gaining popularity and stuff.)

Answer (score 1):

Why would you define a `property` that you never actually set or get? Wouldn't you make your code cleaner and easier to understand for others if you would define a `method` like:

```
-(void)setEndDate:(NSDate *)endDate;
```

You then implement this `method` that assigns a new value to the numberOfNights.

Comment: This is just the header, the .m certainly does implement both the setter and the getter methods itself. More than anything, this is a contrived example for the sake of the question being asked.

Comment: Okay, then please forget my answer, but maybe someone else will get help from it.

Comment: I'm with you @Richard I think that this case should not be a declared property. It just doesn't seem that any of the storage attributes would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The main benefit of properties is the ability to automate the creation of tedious boilerplate code for getters and setters backed by a private ivar. In your case, the property is not backed by an ivar, and it sounds like you're writing a manual getter and setter anyways. Given that, I would say the `@property` syntax is just confusing (as you're finding out). I would just declare 2 methods, and implement them to use `numberOfNights` behind the scenes:

```
- (NSDate *)endDate;
- (void)setEndDate:(NSDate *)date;
```

Otherwise, whatever qualifier you use (retain, copy, assign) will just be ignored since you're manually implementing the accessors.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a scenario where it makes a whole lot of sense to have a write-only property. If the only purpose of the property is to update something else, I'd use a method with a name such as this, so that your code is as unambiguous as possible:

```
- (void)updateNumberOfNightsWithEndDate:(NSDate *)endDate;
```

Property accessors with side-effects can lead to code mess down the track if you're not careful, so in general I try to minimise their use.